# Apache server running but requests returning Cannot connect to server

Tags: php, apache

I have a apache http server running on Unix server which was serving an PHP application till yesterday. Today i'm getting "cannot connect to server" on accessing the application from browser. If i try to start server -

```
-bash-4.1$ ./apachectl start
httpd (pid 19978) already running
```

I tried checking the apache server by sending curl request to localhost -

```
-bash-4.1$ curl http://localhost:80
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

-bash-4.1$ nc -vz localhost 80
nc: connect to localhost port 80 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
nc: connect to localhost port 80 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

logs/error_log :

```
    [Wed May 10 04:43:20 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.1m PHP/5.6.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed May 10 04:46:00 2017] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed May 10 04:46:06 2017] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Wed May 10 04:46:06 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.1m PHP/5.6.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed May 10 04:55:13 2017] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed May 10 04:55:39 2017] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Wed May 10 04:55:39 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.1m PHP/5.6.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed May 10 05:49:51 2017] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed May 10 05:50:11 2017] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Wed May 10 05:50:11 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.1m PHP/5.6.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed May 10 06:28:21 2017] [notice] caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Wed May 10 06:28:39 2017] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Wed May 10 06:28:39 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.1m PHP/5.6.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed May 10 06:28:47 2017] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Wed May 10 06:28:47 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.1m PHP/5.6.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

logs/access_log

```
17.169.113.84 - - [10/May/2017:03:36:36 +0000] "GET /sdk/vimService.wsdl HTTP/1.1" 404 217
17.169.113.84 - - [10/May/2017:03:36:37 +0000] "GET /xmldata?item=all HTTP/1.1" 404 205
17.169.113.84 - - [10/May/2017:03:36:43 +0000] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
17.169.113.84 - - [10/May/2017:04:41:57 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 -
17.169.113.84 - - [10/May/2017:04:41:57 +0000] "GET /login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 33
17.169.113.84 - - [10/May/2017:04:41:58 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 55
17.169.113.84 - - [10/May/2017:04:41:58 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 209
17.169.113.84 - - [10/May/2017:04:41:58 +0000] "GET /login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 33
17.169.113.84 - - [10/May/2017:04:44:03 +0000] "GET /login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 33
17.169.113.84 - - [10/May/2017:04:44:43 +0000] "GET /login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 33
17.169.113.84 - - [10/May/2017:04:44:47 +0000] "GET /login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 33
17.169.113.84 - - [10/May/2017:04:45:27 +0000] "GET /login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 33
17.169.113.84 - - [10/May/2017:04:46:46 +0000] "GET /login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 33
17.169.113.84 - - [10/May/2017:04:57:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 55
17.169.113.84 - - [10/May/2017:04:57:30 +0000] "GET /login.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
17.169.113.84 - - [10/May/2017:05:06:34 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 55
17.169.113.84 - - [10/May/2017:05:06:34 +0000] "GET /login.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
17.169.113.84 - - [10/May/2017:06:13:40 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 55
17.169.113.84 - - [10/May/2017:06:13:40 +0000] "GET /login.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
17.40.176.54 - - [10/May/2017:06:28:21 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 -
17.40.176.54 - - [10/May/2017:06:28:21 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 -
17.40.176.54 - - [10/May/2017:06:28:47 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 -
17.40.176.54 - - [10/May/2017:06:28:47 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 -
17.40.176.54 - - [10/May/2017:06:28:47 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 -
17.40.176.54 - - [10/May/2017:06:28:47 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 -
17.40.176.54 - - [10/May/2017:06:28:47 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 -
17.169.113.84 - - [10/May/2017:06:38:26 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 55
17.169.113.84 - - [10/May/2017:06:38:26 +0000] "GET /login.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
17.169.113.84 - - [10/May/2017:06:44:46 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 55
17.169.113.84 - - [10/May/2017:06:44:46 +0000] "GET /login.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
17.169.113.84 - - [10/May/2017:06:48:05 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 55
17.169.113.84 - - [10/May/2017:06:48:06 +0000] "GET /login.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
```

Can anyone help me identify whats wrong with this server?

Comment: Perhaps httpd is not listening on port 80, try: `sudo netstat -nap | grep LISTE | grep tcp | grep httpd`

Answer (score 0):

"Connection refused" implies that there's somethnig actively blocking the connection. If you are getting this error connecting to localhost, then the problem is local to the machine. Look at your iptables config.